# Assigning a pointer to a reference

Tags: c++

I'm using a library which has a draw function which takes a reference to a circle. I wish to call this function but I have a pointer to my circle object. Can I pass this pointed to object to the draw function? If not, why not?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can.

You have this function

```
void DoSth(/*const*/Circle& c)
{
   ///
}
```

You have this pointer

```
/*const*/ Circle* p = /*...*/;
```

You call it like this

```
DoSth(*p);
```

I suggest that you should read [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This is really fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 6):

As long as pointer is not destroyed while the reference is still being used it is fine.

```
int *p = new int;
int &r = *p;
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, just dereference the pointer, example:

```
void functionToCall(Circle &circle);

//in your code:
Circle *circle = new Circle();
functionToCall(*circle);
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be easier if you'd supply some code of your problem. But basically it would work like this:

```
void func(Circle& circle) {
    // do something
}

...
Circle *pCircle = new Circle();
func(*pCircle);
```